# Xamarin / IOS / Azure - No 'id' member found on type

Tags: ios, azure, asynchronous, xamarin, offline

I have an APP developed in Xamarin Android and works perfectly .
I'm doing the version of IOS Xamarin , but I'm having trouble activating the async Offline Azure .
In the emulator works when the testo Device generates the following error .

*"No 'id' member found on type 'FM.Model.Categoria'."*

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.SQLiteStore;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Sync;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FM.Dados
{
    public class AtualizaDados
    {
        static AtualizaDados instance = new AtualizaDados();

        const string applicationURL = @"https://xxxx.azurewebsites.net";

        private MobileServiceClient client;
        private IMobileServiceSyncTable<Model.Categoria> categoriaTable;

        private AtualizaDados()
        {
            try
            {
                CurrentPlatform.Init();
                SQLitePCL.CurrentPlatform.Init();

                // Initialize the Mobile Service client with the Mobile App URL, Gateway URL and key
                client = new MobileServiceClient(applicationURL);

                // Create an MSTable instance to allow us to work with the TodoItem table
                categoriaTable = client.GetSyncTable<Model.Categoria>();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.Error.WriteLine(@"Sync Failed: {0}", e.Message);
            }
        }

        public static AtualizaDados DefaultService
        {
            get
            {
                return instance;
            }
        }

        public async Task InitializeStoreAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                var store = new MobileServiceSQLiteStore(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "fm.db"));
                store.DefineTable<Model.Categoria>();

                await client.SyncContext.InitializeAsync(store);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Console.Error.WriteLine(@"Sync Failed: {0}", e.Message);
            }
        }

        public async Task SyncAsync(bool pullData = false)
        {
            try
            {
                await client.SyncContext.PushAsync();

                if (pullData)
                {
                    await categoriaTable.PullAsync("allCategoria", categoriaTable.CreateQuery());
                }
            }

            catch (MobileServiceInvalidOperationException e)
            {
                Console.Error.WriteLine(@"Sync Failed: {0}", e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The attribute " Id " exists and still gives error .

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace FM.Model
{
    public class Categoria
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Codigo")]
        public int Codigo { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Nome")]
        public string Nome { get; set; }

        public bool Deleted { get; set; }
    }

}
```

I've looked several user forums with the same error , but no solution solved my problem .
Would anyone have any idea what can be ?
I need some permission since the emulator work?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not defining the store prior to getting the SyncTable.  There is a natural order that is needed here:

1. Create the Client
2. Generate the local store map with DefineTable
3. Initialize the store
4. Get the Sync Table.

Try this:

```
        try
        {
            CurrentPlatform.Init();
            SQLitePCL.CurrentPlatform.Init();

            // Initialize the Mobile Service client with the Mobile App URL, Gateway URL and key
            client = new MobileServiceClient(applicationURL);

            // Initialize the local offline store
            await InitializeStoreAsync();

            // Create an MSTable instance to allow us to work with the TodoItem table
            categoriaTable = client.GetSyncTable<Model.Categoria>();
        }
```

Comment: Adrian Hall, made the change that informed and generated the same error when you run the "store.DefineTable<Model.Categoria>();" the InitializeStoreAsync ()

Comment: You may need to clear the offline cache - just remove the underlying file.

Comment: Also, check permissions on the folder - generally, you don't have to deal with the folder path - just specify the filename - it gets placed in the right place.

Comment: I have to use the option to reset to clear everything.
I have already put the BD only stating the name and also going one way and always got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

In the emulator is working completely, now when I try to run on the device of the error.
Must enable any permission?
I'm not finding anything to report on the error reason.
I've tried to inform the path of the DB file and nothing.